# How to access extended User attributes in django template

Tags: django, templates

I am trying to access extended field of User model in Django template but it doesn't work, there are my files:
`models.py`:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='user', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    bio = models.TextField(
        max_length=1400, help_text="Enter author biography.")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    def create_profile(sender, **kwargs):
        user = kwargs["instance"]
        if kwargs["created"]:
            user_profile = Author(user=user, bio='my bio')
            user_profile.save()
    post_save.connect(create_profile, sender=User)
```

template:

```
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}
{% block title %}
<title>Author {{user}}</title>
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
  <h1>{{user}}</h1>
  <h2>Bio:</h2>
  <p>{{user.author.bio}}</p>
  <div>
    {%for item in user.author.blogs_set.all%}
    <p>{{item.title}}</p>
    <hr> 
    {%endfor%}
  </div>

{% endblock %}
```

views:

```
class UserDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = User
    template_name = 'blogapp/user_detail.html'
```

I want to get access to the bio field through `user.author.bio` but nothing displays I have also tried `user.bio` is there any tricky way to get access to this field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the `related_name` to:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User,
        related_name='user',
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True
    )
```

But the `related_name` is the name to access the related `Author` from a `User` object (so the name of the relation in ***reverse***). You thus should set it to `author` (or leave it blank), like:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User,
        related_name='author',
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True
    )
```

By setting it to `user`, you could have accessed the `Author` object with `user.user`, but I strongly advise *not* to do this, since in the end, it will only result in code that is hard to understand. For Django it of course does not matter (given no two relations originating from `User` have the same name), but for programmers, it gives a wrong impression.

Comment: Thanks now i understand, `related_name` is the same as default `_set`, now works like  a charm

Comment: @tookas92: for `ForeignKey`s yes, but iirc, for `OneToOneField`s, it is just the name of the model in lowercase, since there is at most one such model.